# not all orders getting filled in tradingview pinescript strategy

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm struggling with tradingview strategies, a very basic thing doesn't work for me ... in the strategy, as soon as a signal appears, i want to place multiple limit long orders at certain price levels. in the picture you can see a few rows of white diamong shapes printed. these are the price levels and also the duration for which the limit long orders should be active. however, even though the bars cross through multiple of these price levels, only the first one or two long orders get filled. in this example the price drops even through the lowest level and only 2 out of 5 orders get filled.

in the code for placing the orders you can see that it

```
if (activeorders) //basically "if the white diamonds are being printed"
    if(uselong1) //all 5 are set on true
        strategy.entry("long1", strategy.long,size1contracts,limit=longprice1,when = window(),oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel, oca_name = "long1")
    if(uselong2)
        strategy.entry("long2", strategy.long,size2contracts,limit=longprice2,when = window(),oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel, oca_name = "long2")
    if(uselong3)
        strategy.entry("long3", strategy.long,size3contracts,limit=longprice3,when = window(),oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel, oca_name = "long3")
    if(uselong4)
        strategy.entry("long4", strategy.long,size4contracts,limit=longprice4,when = window(),oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel, oca_name = "long4")
    if(uselong5)
        strategy.entry("long5", strategy.long,size5contracts,limit=longprice5,when = window(),oca_type = strategy.oca.cancel, oca_name = "long5")
```

[the mentioned visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDt9d.png)

ive tried checking for typos etc, checking whether removing some conditions would help, it doesnt, playing with the contract size, it doesnt have any influence.

/////////////
EDIT1:

I noticed one more thing: whenever more than one of these long entries get filled, it's within the same bar. It seems that after the strategy entry was triggered once it disregards any of the following bars, even though the white diamonds (activeorders) are still being printed and the orders should still be sitting there at these price levels. But I couldn't find a single instance in the chart, where a long order was filled one or more bars later than the other. to my understanding they should operate indepentently...?

Comment: without full compilable strategy code it is too hard to assist.

Answer (score 0):

From your description and the attached image, it sounds like you have the if statements nested.

The actual code you are using looks correct, but it needs to be indented differently.

It sounds like you have:

```
if (activeorders)
    if(uselong1)
        strategy.entry("long1",...)
        if(uselong2)
            strategy.entry("long2",...)
            if(uselong3)
                strategy.entry("long3",...)
                if(uselong4)
                    strategy.entry("long4",...)
                    if(uselong5)
                        strategy.entry("long5",...)
```

With this code indentation:

1. You only attempt to evaluate `long1` if `activeorders` was true.
2. You only attempt to evaluate `long2` if `long1` and `activeorders` are both true.
3. You only attempt to evaluate `long3` if `long2`, `long1` and `activeorders` are all true.
4. You only attempt to evaluate `long4` if `long3`, `long2`, `long1` and `activeorders` are all true.
5. You only attempt to evaluate `long5` if `long4` ... `long1` and `activeorders` are all true.

---

What I believe you want, is to check them all individually as long as `activeorders` is true.

The following code layout would test each long regardless of the other ones being true or false:

```
if (activeorders)
    if(uselong1)
        strategy.entry("long1",...)
    if(uselong2)
        strategy.entry("long2",...)
    if(uselong3)
        strategy.entry("long3",...)
    if(uselong4)
        strategy.entry("long4",...)
    if(uselong5)
        strategy.entry("long5",...)
```

Play with your code formatting, specifically the indentation of your code and see if that helps to get the results you desire.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your help.  I didn't realize that the formatting/indenting got destroyed when copypasting the code. Anyway, I'm actually using the 2nd version you're suggesting.

Comment: I noticed one more thing: whenever more than one of these long entries get filled, it's within the same bar. It seems that after the strategy entry was triggered once it disregards any of the following bars, even though the white diamonds (activeorders) are still being printed and the orders should still be sitting there at these price levels. But I couldn't find a single instance in the chart, where a long order was filled one or more bars later than the other. to my understanding they should operate indepentently...?

Comment: If you want to execute multiple entries in the same direction, did you set up pyramiding?  https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/set-strategy-pyramiding/